# In a Blazor NET8 a component can't find RenderFragment and the Context

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have created a component for Blazor with NET7 that is working. I published the full source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorAutocomplete). I want to use the same component in a NET8 Blazor application.

In a new page in the client project in the NET8 Blazor application, I added this code (this code is working fine with another project build with NET7)

```
<Autocomplete SearchMethod="GetTagLocal"
                @bind-Value="SelectedTag"
                Multiselect="_isMultiselect"
                EnableDropDown="true"
                placeholder="Search by verb..."
                ResultContainerCSS="tag-container"
                ResultItemCSS="tag-item">
    <SelectedTemplate Context="tag">
        @tag?.WordName
    </SelectedTemplate>
    <ResultTemplate Context="tag">
        <div class="tag-result-item-container">
            <div class="tag-result-item">
                <div class="tag-label">@tag?.WordName</div>
                <div class="tag-count"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ResultTemplate>
</Autocomplete>
```

[image]

Now, I have those new errors:

- The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-Value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.
- The name 'tag' does not exist in the current context

The `SelectedTemplate` and `ResultTemplate` are defined as

```
[Parameter] 
public RenderFragment<TValue>? SelectedTemplate { get; set; }
[Parameter] 
public RenderFragment<TItem>? ResultTemplate { get; set; }
```

As you can see in the XAML, I use the `Context` that gives the current rendering object. So, I can use it to display the `WordName` for example.

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: judging by looking at the color of the code in the IDE it doesn't look like it recognizes the component at all. Have you added the necessary usings in the imports.razor and added references to where the Autocomplete component is declared?

Comment: yes, I added in the _Imports.razor_ the component

Comment: Well your component is not being recognized, try adding a built in component like InputNumber to the same file and you should see it coloured green. That mean's vs recognizes that it's a component.

Comment: currently your code is being interpreted as arbitrary html elements.

Comment: You are right. I cleaned the solution, rebuilt 3/4 times and it is working. Thank you @RBee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases where adding your code as image was necessary to find a solution. By seeing how Visual studio(VS) colours your `Autocomplete` component we can see that it's not being recognized as a component. In the default theme VS will add a green colour to components, the same colour used for Classes.

If your components are not coloured as such then there is likely some VS configuration issues such as missing usings and references, which is causing the component to not be recognized as a component.

From the comments you found a fix for this by performing a `dotnet clean` and rebuilding the project.